# How to create a column that creates a value for multiple rows based on other values only in certain rows of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe (dset) which has the details of lots of study participants (studynr). At each study visit, the date (med_dt) and the total number of medications that the participant was prescribed (TOTAL) was recorded. See dummy data below:

```
dates <- seq(c(ISOdate(2010,1,1)), c(ISOdate(2020,1,1)), by = "day")
dset <- data.frame(studynr = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5), 
                   med_dt = (sample(dates, size=15, replace=TRUE)),
                   TOTAL = c(7,9,10,8,7,9,10,8,6,5,8,10,15,12,10))

   studynr              med_dt TOTAL
1        1 2018-03-27 12:00:00     7
2        1 2015-03-16 12:00:00     9
3        1 2010-04-01 12:00:00    10
4        2 2018-08-17 12:00:00     8
5        2 2016-10-08 12:00:00     7
6        2 2019-06-23 12:00:00     9
7        3 2018-06-25 12:00:00    10
8        3 2017-07-09 12:00:00     8
9        3 2011-09-02 12:00:00     6
10       4 2010-07-05 12:00:00     5
11       4 2011-02-11 12:00:00     8
12       4 2012-04-14 12:00:00    10
13       5 2017-09-20 12:00:00    15
14       5 2015-08-31 12:00:00    12
15       5 2017-08-22 12:00:00    10
```

What I want to do is assign a new categorical column (baseline_med) which is assigned A if the number of medications that a participant was taking at their first visit was <=8, and B if it was >8.

```
   studynr              med_dt TOTAL baseline_med
1        1 2018-03-27 12:00:00     7            B
2        1 2015-03-16 12:00:00     9            B
3        1 2010-04-01 12:00:00    10            B
4        2 2018-08-17 12:00:00     8            A
5        2 2016-10-08 12:00:00     7            A
6        2 2019-06-23 12:00:00     9            A
7        3 2018-06-25 12:00:00    10            A
8        3 2017-07-09 12:00:00     8            A
9        3 2011-09-02 12:00:00     6            A
10       4 2010-07-05 12:00:00     5            A
11       4 2011-02-11 12:00:00     8            A
12       4 2012-04-14 12:00:00    10            A
13       5 2017-09-20 12:00:00    15            B
14       5 2015-08-31 12:00:00    12            B
15       5 2017-08-22 12:00:00    10            B
```

My current working is to first order the visits for each participant by date (so I can identify the baseline study visit), then to strip the data back to just the first visit for each participant, then assign A or B using the `cut` function. But I cannot work out how to then extrapolate this back into the full dset.

```
dset <- dset[order(dset$studynr, dset$med_dt)]
dset <- data_unique(dset, select = "studynr", keep = "first")
dset$baseline_meds <- cut(dset$TOTAL,
                breaks=c(0, 9, Inf),
                labels=c('A', 'B'),  
                right = FALSE)
```

I can't help but feel there must be an easier way to achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dset %>%
  group_by(studynr) %>%
  mutate(baseline_med = case_when(
    med_dt == min(med_dt) & TOTAL <= 8 ~ 'A',
    med_dt == min(med_dt) & TOTAL > 8 ~ 'B',
    TRUE ~ NA
  )) %>%
  fill(baseline_med, .direction = 'updown') %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 15 × 4
#>    studynr med_dt              TOTAL baseline_med
#>      <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>       
#>  1       1 2012-12-13 12:00:00     7 A           
#>  2       1 2013-07-03 12:00:00     9 A           
#>  3       1 2017-06-01 12:00:00    10 A           
#>  4       2 2012-10-23 12:00:00     8 A           
#>  5       2 2017-10-24 12:00:00     7 A           
#>  6       2 2016-11-12 12:00:00     9 A           
#>  7       3 2016-05-27 12:00:00    10 B           
#>  8       3 2017-09-25 12:00:00     8 B           
#>  9       3 2018-09-01 12:00:00     6 B           
#> 10       4 2019-06-05 12:00:00     5 B           
#> 11       4 2015-06-11 12:00:00     8 B           
#> 12       4 2015-03-31 12:00:00    10 B           
#> 13       5 2017-02-07 12:00:00    15 B           
#> 14       5 2017-12-21 12:00:00    12 B           
#> 15       5 2014-09-19 12:00:00    10 B
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you - this has worked perfectly. Was not aware of `fill` but that is exactly what I was looking for.